# ckeditor 5 - How do you get the editor data?

Tags: ckeditor5

I have the following div:

```
<div name="content" id="editor">
```

I have the following script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // CKEDITORs
        var myeditor = ClassicEditor
            .create(document.querySelector('#editor'))
            .then(editor => {
                console.log(editor);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    });

    const data = editor.getData();
    const data = myeditor.getData();

</script>
```

From the documentation, I thought I would be able to do the following:

```
const data = editor.getData(); //fails with editor.getData is not a function
```

So added the myeditor var as above and tried this:

```
myeditor.getData();// also fails with same error.
```

How do I get data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get value of CKEditor 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47013985/how-to-get-value-of-ckeditor-5)

Answer (score 4):

Usually the creditor data  is obtained as

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editorid.getData();
```

But in CKEditor 5 there's no single global editor instance like old versions so we have to manually create a instance to hold the data globally to get the data when needed.

```
let editorinstance;
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function () {
    // CKEDITORs 
    var myeditor = ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector('#editor'))
    .then
    (editor => { editorinstance =editor;})
    .catch(error => { 
        console.error(error); 
        }); 
}); 

const data = editorinstance.getData(); 
</script>
```

Comment: That is how it's done in ckeditor ->> 4 <<-. ckeditor 5 has been completely rewritten.

Comment: Before even answering completely I have mistakenly submitted, edited now. Ps: submitted via mobile so code formatting might not be good

Comment: @Scott can you try with **<textarea  id="editor" name="content"></textarea>** instead of loading the editor into a **div** <div name="content" id="editor">??

Comment: The decision was made to go back to version 4, since 5 isn't ready. Therefore I will not be marking an answer as correct. thanks for the help.